# Making Ben Alman's code work for my site

Tags: jquery, hash, hashchange

I am using a ajax called pages and trying to make the browser's "back" and "forward" buttons work.
I tried to use ben alman's plugin cause it seemed to be most popular but does not work for me at this time. I want to know what the problem is. I am pretty shure that is something simple in the code which i do not understand, so please help. I will show you every code :) :

These are the handlers:

```
<li><a href="#" class="ceni">примерни цени</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="karieri">кариери</a></li>
```

And this is my javascript that calls the pages to appear without reloading the whole page(the ajax ):

```
$('.ceni').click(function(){             
    $.ajax({
    url: 'pages/ceni.php',
    success: function(response) {
    $("#pages").html(response);
    }
     });    
  });



  $('.karieri').click(function(){           
    $.ajax({
    url: 'pages/karieri.php',
    success: function(response) {
    $("#pages").html(response);
    }
     });        
  });
```

And these are the ben alman's code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(function(){

  // Keep a mapping of url-to-container for caching purposes.
  var cache = {
    // If url is '' (no fragment), display this div's content.
    '': $('.bbq-default')
  };

  // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the history state changes,
  // gets the url from the hash and displays either our cached content or fetches
  // new content to be displayed.
  $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

    // Get the hash (fragment) as a string, with any leading # removed. Note that
    // in jQuery 1.4, you should use e.fragment instead of $.param.fragment().
    var url = $.param.fragment();

    // Remove .bbq-current class from any previously "current" link(s).
    $( 'a.bbq-current' ).removeClass( 'bbq-current' );

    // Hide any visible ajax content.
    $( '.bbq-content' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();

    // Add .bbq-current class to "current" nav link(s), only if url isn't empty.
    url && $( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).addClass( 'bbq-current' );

    if ( cache[ url ] ) {
      // Since the element is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be
      // created, so instead of creating it again, let's just show it!
      cache[ url ].show();

    } else {
      // Show "loading" content while AJAX content loads.
      $( '.bbq-loading' ).show();

      // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
      // the cache.
      cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="bbq-item"/>' )

        // Append the content container to the parent container.
        .appendTo( '.bbq-content' )

        // Load external content via AJAX. Note that in order to keep this
        // example streamlined, only the content in .infobox is shown. You'll
        // want to change this based on your needs.
        .load( url, function(){
          // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
          $( '.bbq-loading' ).hide();
        });
    }
  })

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );

});

$(function(){

  // Syntax highlighter.
  SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();

});

</script>
```

Note: I am not a specialist or something, so please talk to me simply as you can. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are there any error messages in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes, you can see ot here. http://athome.webege.com/LD@/

Comment: It'd be better to include the errors _here_, rather than ask everyone to re-generate their own each time. (At some point, you'll probably take that page down, losing the errors for all eternity.)

Comment: Thank you for you time, but i don't want to extend the question and don't relly believe that could help. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

The BBQ plugin is not going to magically make the back and forward buttons work.  The BBQ plugin just makes it easier to change the browser hash (and also supporting multiple hash values).  You still need to change the hash yourself.

Read a bit more about hashing here ....

https://developers.google.com/tv/web/articles/location-hash-navigation

Comment: For the awesome link !! +!